# $\sin(2\pi q)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, algebraic-numbers

Let $q$ be an element of $\mathbb{Q}$ (rational numbers). How can I prove that $\sin (2\pi q)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ for any $q$?
I am trying the method: Euler formula: $e^{i\theta} =\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$
so $2\sin\theta = ie^{i\theta}-ie^{-i\theta}$.
$i$ is root of $x^2+1$. So if I prove that $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$f or $\theta=2\pi q$, it will be ok.

Comment: Trusted users (and also others) are encouraged to search before posting. [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=extension%20degree%2C%20%24%5Csin%5C%20%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%20p%7D%7Bq%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1) often gives better results, if the key phrase includes a TeX-snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $q=\frac mn$, with $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ and $n>0$, then$$e^{2\pi iq}=e^{2\pi i\frac mn},$$which is algebraic, since it is a root of $x^n-1$.

Comment: Thank you @José Carlos Santos